# Using Pandas to group data in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pandas to group data in a column1, but nothing I have been trying has worked. Basically, I want all data in column 2 to merge with column 1. Let me give you example data:

```
COL1      COL2
123       2
442       2
312       2
411       1
412       1
```

I would like the data to look like this:

```
COL1      COL2
2          3
1          2
```

Comment: What is the exact algorithm for creating the expected output here? The question definitely needs more explanation.

Comment: how the result for COL1 is computed from COL1 above?

Comment: @naveed I dont need the specific numbers in COL1, I just want to know how many times there are X instances of a specific number in column 1.

Answer (score 0):

How/why you are getting from start to end isn't super clear, but it may be that you just want to do a groupby?

```py
df.groupby('COL2').count()
      COL1
COL2
1        2
2        3
```

This is taking the values that exist in 'COL2' (1 and 2) and counting how many times those values show up in 'COL2'. That is, 1 shows up twice, and 2 shows up 3 times. This doesn't use 'COL1' at all, really. It is unclear from your example what 'COL1' is for at all.

This of course has the names of the columns backwards from what you started with. If you want, you can reset/rename them

```py
df = df.groupby('COL2').count()
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'COL1':'COL2','COL2':'COL1'})
```

Comment: Let me try and explain it better. I have a load of information, like 400,000 lines of data, and I do not need the exact data that exists in COL1. I would just like to merge the data between column 1 and 2 and I need something that merges, for example, all of the data that is the same in column2 and just tells me how much data it merged. For this example, I have 3 instances of  2 and I just need that information.

Comment: does what i wrote do what you need on your full dataset?